# How to block loading http stream urls in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, tvos

Using ATS security Allow Arbitrary Loads to False is not blocking the AVPlayer HTTP URLs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia = false`

Source: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloadsformedia)

Comment: NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia to false also not blocking the HTTP stream URL which we give to the Avplayer

Comment: @BASILBABY Can you share your ATS settings in .plist file.

Comment: issue resolved: The stream URL server which we are using should support secure connections. I was using a simple HTTP sample URL available in internet. and it was not getting blocked. Then I tried to use the HTTP HLS stream URLs and its getting blocked